# What are the long term visa extension offices of Bangkok (excluding Samut Prakan province) in 2024?

Tags: thailand

At least now in January 2024 in the north of Bangkok there is **IT Sqare Lak-Si** immigration division for short term visa extensions but what are the long term visa extension offices of Bangkok (excluding Samut Prakan province)?

From my knowledge, there are two other ones, also in the north of Bangkok and actually 10 minutes drive away from there:

- Immigration division 1, **Building B floor 1** in Sun Rachakan (ศูนย์ราชการ) on Chaeng Watthana Road (ถนนแจ้งวัฒนะ) for long term visas.
- Immigration division 1, **Building B floor 2** in Sun Rachakan (ศูนย์ราชการ) on Chaeng Watthana Road (ถนนแจ้งวัฒนะ) for reporting and follow ups such as **TM-30** report or **TM-47** report ("90 days report") and possibly other reports.

If I am not mistaken there is also a special center for work permit issuance not far from Si-Lom area.